# Connecting SqliteDB via appsetting.json file triggers 'Data Source cannot be empty. Use :memory: to open an in-memory database'

Tags: c#, sqlite, connection-string

I am trying to connecting my web application to a SQLite db via an appsetting.json file.

This is my appsetting.json file

```
 {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqlDb": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=HotelAppDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False",
    "SqliteDb": "‪Data Source=C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\HotelAppDB.db;Version=3;"
  },
  "DatabaseChoice": "SQLite"
}
```

Please ignore the "SqlDb" connection, which is working at the moment.  However, when I tested my SqliteDb connectionstring. VS return an error as follow:

[image]

The Sqlite database is sitting at my desktop, as followed

[image]

I put a breakpoint in my code, the local windows indicate the application actually got the location of my sqlite db.
[image]
How to dissolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The location of the SQLite file doesn't seems matching in your screenshot it seems you placed it on Desktop and in your connection string you are looking at it in the Documents folder may you check that.

Comment: ... and your appsetting does not contain "Data Source=" yet it shows in your locals window. What you are showing is not matching up to what is happening.

Comment: I just changed the access location of the db file. it is still notworking.